# Bootstrap Pagination between navigation elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I tried different plugins like bootstrap-paginator and bootstrap-pagination-js to make pagination through dynamically generated `<li>` elements , so that they don't exceed one line.

The wanted result : One line of dates with next and previous buttons respectively in the right and in the left .

The plugins that I've tried have not been useful to me .

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">      
        <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills text-center">         
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">
                <span class="text-center badge pull-right span-list">1</span>
                1 Mars
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">2 Mars</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">3 Mars</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">4 Mars</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">etc</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

The code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ELfQ/) .

Your suggestions will be very welcome .

Comment: Have either of the answers addressed your issue? If not, could you be please elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you having a problem with styling? If so...

I've set the row height to fixed, and made overflow hidden, so that you get just one row of buttons.

```
.row{overflow:hidden;height:42px;}
```

I've added a prev and next button, and made them float left and right respectively. I hope this doesn't violate your pagination framework. Please let me know if you want an example of how to programmatically add these elements.

HTML

```
<li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
<li class="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
```

CSS

```
li.next{float:right;}
li.prev{float:left;}
```

I believe this gives the desired result... please let me know if I've missed your intention.

**Disclaimer:** I've only tested this in Opera 19.0. I don't have access to Firefox/Chrome/IE at the moment.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/5ELfQ/2/

**Updated:** Updated to remove horizontal scrollbar. - http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/5ELfQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with Bootstrap pagination. If you are generating too many elements to fit in your desired space, you need to either figure out a way to generate less or use css to limit the size of your pagination space and "cut off" the overflowing elements.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is .prepend() a left li and .append() a right li:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav').prepend('<li class="left"><a>Left</a></li>');
$('.nav').append('<li class="right"><a>Right</a></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there has little browser compatibility and styling issues in this solution. But I hope this will give you an idea to start.

My CSS:

```
.nav.nav-pills {
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills > li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: none !important;
}
.nav-pills > li.last {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

As `display:inline;` is applied to `.nav`, so for centering use `text-center` class in wrapping div. i.e.

```
<div class="col-md-12 column text-center">
```

Apply jQuery for previous/next buttons and resizing issues.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav').prepend('<li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>');
    $('.nav').append('<li class="last"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>');

    var ulWidth = $('.nav').width();
    var screenWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        if (screenWidth < ulWidth ){
            $('.nav').css('width', '100%');
        }

        $(window).resize(function(){
            screenWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            screenWidth < ulWidth == true ?
            $('.nav').css('width', '100%') :
            $('.nav').css('width', 'auto');
        });
});
```